# Saving a value when destroying an activity, then restore it

Tags: java, android

Say `ActivityA` with two buttons. Each of these button will open `ActivityB` but with a different fragment respectively. Both fragment contain an `EditText`. If I want to switch fragment while in `ActivityB`, I need to return to `ActivityA` and press the other button.

Now what I want to do is to save the value entered in each `EditText` when I switch fragment or close the app and repopulate the value in the right `EditText` when I re-open the fragment.

It seems to do it by it self when I open the `SettingActivity` then come back, but not if I destroy the activity. In the end I want the fragment to re-open just as I left it. Thank you.

Comment: Finally : is the question how to save data when the app is closed/minimized ?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "close the app"?  Should the input be saved when you press the back button from `ActivityA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save value and then restore them.A good way is Shared Preferences.
**1-save:**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("var1", edittext.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
```

**2-restore:**

```
String s = sharedpreferences.getString("var1","DEF");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference to store the value
 When you call your new activity use this

```
 SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("userEmail", youredittext.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
```

When you want to retrieve the stored value in any of your activities, get it like this

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
   String mUserEmail = getPrefs.getString("userEmail", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have more fields or like you want to maintain relation for data.. in that case you also can use SQLite. Below is post on SQLite

http://www.kpblogs.com/mobile-development/sqlite-android-tutorial-with-crud-operations/